# React Native and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, undefined

i am building usermanagement system with expo cli, react native and aws amplify as the backend i got stuck at this error. any help, thanks in advance

TypeError: (0, _core.parseAWSExports) is not a function. (In '(0, _core.parseAWSExports)(config)', '(0, _core.parseAWSExports)' is undefined)

i try to use aws amplify as the backend of my react native native, but it is throwing error

Comment: When do you get that error, what triggers it?

Comment: Hello Aaron thanks for reaching out i got the error 1 Week Ago

Comment: ...when *during execution* does the error occur? The second you run the code, after a certain function? Have you used breakpoints and/or logging to locate the source?

Comment: The error occur  1 min after the code was launch the build was successful but error is coming from aws. now i am trying to use React-Native cli and see how things will come out